# KVM-virtualization Host and Guest NoGraphics

Tags: kvm-virtualization

i was wondering is it possible to run a virtualized KVM host with no graphics. i dont want to install x11 on the host or the guest either for that matter, they are only going to run linux console fileserv. and testing envoir...

im new to virtualization and kvm and kvm-qemu gets me confused, can't i just run kvm?. what do i need and where to start?.

scenario: 
Host running archlinux clean without no x11.
want guests running ex. Gentoo and other distros without no x11.

Comment: Of course this is possible. What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

Yes just install Centos Minimal or any other distro that doesnt have X Windows by default, and then run `yum -y groupinstall Virtualization`  You can connect to the host via ssh, and you can access the VMs using VNC initially with a small amount of configuration needed.  Qemu doesnt mean you need X Windows.  KVM is the linux kernel module for virtualization and Qemu is a simple emulation platform that works together with KVM.  Libvirtd is the management library that provides the virsh commands on the CLI.  I never use X Windows on my KVM hosts.